# How to apply DeMorgan's law in this C logical operation?

Tags: c

I want to compare three values if they're unique or not, and here's my first statement, which I want to simplify and make it more readable using the DeMorgan's Law.

```
product1Id != product2Id && product1Id != product3Id
```

Comment: `!(product1Id == product2Id || product1Id == product3Id)`

Comment: I don't see any need to change the expression, as long as it works and does as expected. It's clear and readable as it is.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ohh, I thought there can be a simplified version of it by using the DeMorgan's Law, but as Eugene Sh. have mentioned, I need to rethink it. Thanks though!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude IMHO, the rewritten expression is easier to understand. Multiple negations often get confusing, and they're frequently the cause of logic errors.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the way we write multiple conditions in boolean expressions doesn't mirror how we say them in English. This results in the frequent beginner errors like "if x == 1 || 2`.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps one of the downsides of being *too* experienced, even rather complex expressions seems simple... ;)

Comment: What if the three values are (1, 2, 2), they're not unique.

Comment: You're going to have to check whether `product2Id` is equal to `product3Id` to ensure that the three values are all distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to compare three values if they're unique or not,

Your code doesn't ensure that. C(3,2) = 3!/2!/(3-2)! = 3 comparisons are needed, but you only have two. The following is the correct check:

```c
product1Id != product2Id &&
product1Id != product3Id &&
product2Id != product3Id
```

---

> I want to simplify and make it more readable

DeMorgan's laws can be used to obtain

```c
!( product1Id == product2Id || product1Id == product3Id )
```

(See a few ways this is done below.)

It's debatable whether this is more readable or not.

But maybe the `!( )` can be left out by exchanging the "then" and "else" clauses of an `if` statement, simplifying the expression to just

```c
product1Id == product2Id || product1Id == product3Id
```

Also, say you had to repeatedly make this check with different values for `product1Id`, and say you had a large number of product ids against with to check. Then one could use

```c
// Setup
ProductSet *set = ProductSet_new();
ProductSet_add( set, product2Id );
ProductSet_add( set, product3Id );

!( ProductSet_has( set, product1Id ) )
```

---

> How to apply DeMorgan's law in this C logical operation?

**Approach 1: Starting from `!( A && B )` or `!( A || B )`**

Let's start by synthesizing this form by introducing a double-negation.

```c
!( !( product1Id != product2Id && product1Id != product3Id ) )
      |----------A-----------|    |----------B-----------|
   |----------------------!( A && B )----------------------|
```

Now, we can apply DeMorgan's second law (`!( A && B )` ⇔ `!A || !B`).

```c
   |--------------------------!A || !B--------------------------|
   |------------!A-------------|    |------------!B-------------|
      |----------A-----------|         |----------B-----------|
!( !( product1Id != product2Id ) || !( product1Id != product3Id ) )
```

Let's simplify using `A == B` ⇔ `!( A != B )`.

```c
!( product1Id == product2Id || product1Id == product3Id )
```

**Approach 2a: Starting from `!A && !B` or `!A || !B`**

Let's start by synthesizing this form by introducing double-negations.

```c
!( !( product1Id != product2Id ) ) && !( !( product1Id != product3Id ) )
   |-------------A-------------|         |-------------B-------------|
|---------------!A---------------|    |---------------!B---------------|
|-------------------------------!A && !B-------------------------------|
```

Now, we can apply DeMorgan's first law (`!( A || B )` ⇔ `!A && !B`).

```c
|---------------------------!( A || B )---------------------------|
   |---------------------------A || B---------------------------|
   |-------------A-------------|    |-------------B-------------|
!( !( product1Id != product2Id ) || !( product1Id != product3Id ) )
```

Let's simplify using `!( A != B )` ⇔ `A == B`.

```c
!( product1Id == product2Id || product1Id == product3Id )
```

**Approach 2b: Starting from `!A && !B` or `!A || !B`**

Let's start by synthesizing this form using `A != B` ⇔ `!( A == B )`.

```c
!( product1Id == product2Id ) && !( product1Id == product3Id )
   |----------A-----------|         |----------B-----------|
|------------!A-------------|    |------------!B-------------|
|--------------------------!A && !B --------------------------|
```

Now, we can apply DeMorgan's first law (`!( A || B )` ⇔ `!A && !B`).

```c
|----------------------!( A || B )----------------------|
   |----------------------A || B----------------------|
   |----------A-----------|    |----------B-----------|
!( product1Id == product2Id || product1Id == product3Id )
```